# what is the impact of restoring security db from old marklogic version to new marklogic?

Tags: backup, marklogic, restore

I backup the database from the MarkLogic server (with version 9.0-10.4) and restored it to another MarkLogic server (with version 10.0-3)
During the process, by mistake, I also restore the security, triggers, and schema db from the old to the new version

is there any kind of impact of that on the MarkLogic server(version 10.0-3)?

After the restoration, the following window came and I continued it:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Aside from ensuring that you manually upgrade the Security DB, to ensure that there isn't a mismatch between the Security DB content and the running version of the MarkLogic cluster software (see below), there is also the concern/risk that any users/roles/permissions that you had/need and were not included in that older backup would be lost and might need to be re-created.

For the other auxiliary databases, if their backups were restored from a different cluster, then the database IDs will be different. Any Triggers or Amps that you may have would need to be updated. They would have invalid database IDs pointing to the Modules database from the source cluster.

- [sec:amps-change-modules-database](https://docs.marklogic.com/sec:amps-change-modules-database)
- [trgr:triggers-change-modules-database](https://docs.marklogic.com/trgr:triggers-change-modules-database)

[Restoring from a different server version](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/restoring-security-database/0)

> When restoring the Security database from a backup made on an older version of ML server to a newer version of ML, a manual upgrade of the Security db is also required after the restore. Without this additional step, there is a mismatch between the server version and the security database version and some features will not work as expected. There will be issues with reindexing, query results,etc.
>
> A security database upgrade can be done by navigating to Admin UI -> 'Support' tab -> click on 'Upgrade' button on the bottom right corner
>
> *Note that MarkLogic does not support restoring a backup made on a newer version of MarkLogic Server onto an older version of MarkLogic Server.*

Comment: Should we replicate security db in this case from the replica cluster?